# Correct way to use axios interceptors

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt

I want to add jwt token to my axiosinstance in Login.js but it is giving me error

> IDX12729: Unable to decode the header '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded ...]

Here is my code:

**Login.js**

```
const printValues = e =>{

      axiosInstance.post('/auth', data)
.then(res =>{

  console.log("adding token");
  
  const config = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    
    config.headers.Authorization =  res.data.token;

    return config;
  });

  axiosInstance.get('/User/GetUserByID/0', config)
  .then(res =>{
    //set user details
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Comment: the first request does not need authorization header, only second one does

Comment: Have you inspected what `res.data.token` actually contain?

Comment: yes it all works good if I use it directly in  the headers, I will add details of what is working in my post

Comment: What is `data` in that `POST /auth` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't define interceptors within a response handler. That means you'll be adding an interceptor every time you make that request.

Typically you would keep your token state and interceptor separate from other application code. Wherever you created your `axiosInstance` is a good candidate.

For example...

```js
import axios from "axios"

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  // ..
})

const token = null // initial state

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
  if (!token) {
    // note, use a separate axios instance for this request
    const { data } = await axios.post("/auth", dataFromSomewhere)
    token = data.token
  }

  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}` // you may need "Bearer" here
  return config
})
```

Now you can use `axiosInstance` to make requests and it will transparently resolve your authorisation token if required before continuing.

```js
const printValues = e => {
  axiosInstance.get("/User/GetUserByID/0")
  .then(res =>{
    //set user details
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Comment: Where I created my axios instance it is at the application start..it does not have token at that point because it executes before login and I get the token only after Login is done..which is login.js..will the above code still work?

Comment: @Samra it should, provided the login `dataFromSomewhere` is actually available for the interceptor

Comment: Thankyou!...I have added more details to my question if you can please have a look

Comment: @Samra please don't fundamentally change your question. It invalidates any existing responses. If you have a new question, then create a new post

Comment: ok i will post a new one and link you there thanks again

Comment: Here is my other question @Phil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934555/where-to-add-remove-interceptors-while-different-components-are-calling-apis-usi

Comment: I had to add 'Bearer ' in order to remove the error

Answer (score 2):

`use` doesn't return a config for you to pass into requests. As long as you are using the same instance, the config would get altered.

```
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    
    config.headers.Authorization =  res.data.token;

    return config;
  });

  axiosInstance.get('/User/GetUserByID/0')
  .then(res =>{
    //set user details
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  })
```